# Why can't my code find the module in the same directory?

Tags: python

It is very strange that I have some python code in the same directory:

```
project-root
  dialog
    tools
       benchmark.py
       populator.py
       template.py
       data.py
```

Then I can import "populator.py" and "template.py" as follows:

```
from dialog.tools.populator import populate
from dialog.tools.template import temp
```

However, it reports an error when I do:

```
from dialog.tools.data import compute
```

The imported 'populate', 'temp' and 'compute' are all functions.

The error message is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dialog.tools.data'
```

As a matter of fact, this worked before. It started to produce this error message after I put several independent projecgts into one git repository. This shouldn't affect this at all. This project alone doesn't change at all.

The question, why the module is reported as not found? Exactly the same as other two in the same directory.

Comment: I looked at that link, and I did have the __init__.py empty file in the "tools" directory. My problem seems unique.

Comment: Do you have `__init__.py` in `dialog`?

Comment: Yes， i do . It worked before. It started to give this error message after I put several projects into one git repository. In the past, these projects are in their own repositories. It shouldn't affect at all. Right? I didn't change anything.

Comment: True. Sorry that I missed the part where you mentioned that you were able to do `from dialog.tools.populator import populate` but just not `from dialog.tools.data import compute`. This is quite strange indeed then.

Comment: @blhsing I re-run 'pip install .' and the problem went away. Probably I have to update my library, even if they are in the same directory of the same project? 'data' is a new module I created.